# OS X 10.7 Lion: Reset master password to FileVault 2

Tags: security, password, filevault

I need to reset or delete my master password to FileVault 2. This is the password found under System Preferences > Users & Groups > Service gear > Change Master Password. It's a backup in case a user forgets his or her account password.

(I accidentally set said password before writing it down in an awkward keyboard fumble.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's surprisingly simple.

- Delete `/Library/Keychains/FileVaultMaster.keychain`
- Delete `/Library/Keychains/FileVaultMaster.cer`

When you return to set a new password your old one will have been cleared.

Based on step 4 in [How to create and deploy a recovery key for FileVault 2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5077).